# Javascript are injecting style and divs when has checkbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

How can I prevent some script on the page from affecting the style and creating new divs within my code?
 
For example, I'm currently creating code like this:

```
<div class="group-checkbox">
     <label for="Hot">
         <div>Enabled</div>
         <input id="Hot" name="Hot" type="checkbox" {Hot}>
     </label>
</div>
```

But when the page is executed, there is some script that is adding other divs when there is a checkbox on the page.
So the result inside my class class="group-checkbox" looks like below:

```
<div class="group-checkbox">
     <label for="Enabled">
       <div>Enabled</div>
       <div class="section">
         <label class="field switch switch-round switch-primary small">
           <input id="Hot-16738839498762826" name="Enabled" type="checkbox" undefined="" data-form-initialized="true">
           <label for="Hot-16738839498762826" data-on="" data-off=""></label>
         </label>
       </div>
     </label>
   </div>
```

I don't want these custom styles, and I would like to prevent it from adding these additional divs, when there is a checkbox on the page inside my class='group-checkbox'
 
   Is there any way to prevent this? (Additional info, I don't have access to the imported .js files so I can't remove it, but I can add some code to prevent it from doing so)
 
   Thanks

Comment: It's probably not a script adding the elements, rather it's your framework at the server. Try to remove `{Hot}` from inside the input tag.

Comment: There's nothing you can do to prevent JS from modifying the DOM.

Answer (score 0):

Would suggest creating your element after the page is loaded with javascript itself. if there is jQuery, then try it like

replace your checkbox html with

```
<div id="checkbox-container-div"></div>
```

and add it to your checkbox from jquery like this

```
jQuery('document').ready(function(){
    jQuery('#checkbox-container-div').html('<div class="group-checkbox"><label for="Hot"><div>Enabled</div><input id="Hot" name="Hot" type="checkbox" {Hot}></label></div>');
});
```

Hope it works